# Make the name of BOOKMARKS unchangeable in QGIS

Tags: qgis, bookmarks

I am working in a large area and I need to use Bookmarks in QGIS. 
When I click on them to zoom in in the interested area, accidentally I can change its name.

Is there any option to make Names as ReadOnly or to not have the opportunity to change them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let's say YES, there is an option. Change to version 3.10 will change the position for bookmarks. From 3.10 on, they will be available in the browser menu, and you will not change them while clicking on the bookmark. So the best option will be updating QGIS to 3.10.

[image]

[image]